# Question on percentages(Pollution in the atmosphere)

Tags: percentages

[image]

What I tried:

$$20*(1-\frac{80}{100})^n=0.01$$
$$=>(\frac{2}{10})^n=\frac{1}{2000}$$

But by this n is not having any integer value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write this as a logarithm, which can be converted into $\log_{2/10} \frac{1}{2000} = n$. By the change of base formula, we have $n = \frac{ \ln{1/2000} } {\ln{2/10} }$, which equals approximately $4.723$.

Now, the question asks you *"how many days will the pollution return to normal levels"*. Notice it takes around $4.723$ days for the pollution to reach its normal level **exactly**. Will the pollution be cleaned up in $4$ days? How about in $5$ days?